# google DLP Masking not working for characters which i want to ignore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dlp, pii

I am trying to use Google DLP to Mask PII information using below code.

```
from typing import List
import google.cloud.dlp_v2

def deidentify_with_mask(
    project: str,
    input_str: str,
    info_types: List[str],
    masking_character: str = None,
    number_to_mask: int = 0,
    charactersToIgnore : list[str]=None

) -> None:
 

    # Instantiate a client
    dlp = google.cloud.dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient()

    # Convert the project id into a full resource id.
    parent = f"projects/{project}"

    # Construct inspect configuration dictionary
    inspect_config = {"info_types": [{"name": info_type} for info_type in info_types]}

    # Construct deidentify configuration dictionary
    deidentify_config = {
        "info_type_transformations": {
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "primitive_transformation": {
                        "character_mask_config": {
                            "masking_character": masking_character,
                            "number_to_mask": number_to_mask,
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    # Construct item
    item = {"value": input_str}

    # Call the API
    response = dlp.deidentify_content(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "deidentify_config": deidentify_config,
            "inspect_config": inspect_config,
            "item": item,
        }
    )

    # Print out the results.
    print(response.item.value)


# Replace with your project ID
project_id = "sandydev"

# Specify the input string, info types, masking character, and number to mask
input_string = "My name is Alicia Abernathy, and my email address is aabernathy@example.com."
info_types = ["EMAIL_ADDRESS"]
masking_character = "*"
number_to_mask = 25

# Call the deidentify_with_mask function
deidentify_with_mask(
    project=project_id,
    input_str=input_string,
    info_types=info_types,
    masking_character=masking_character,
    number_to_mask=number_to_mask,
    charactersToIgnore=["@"]
)
```

the required output is :

```
My name is Alicia Abernathy, and my email address is ##########@#######.###.
```

but is coming as :

```
My name is Alicia Abernathy, and my email address is **********************
```

I want to ignore characters like '@' but is masking that also. Need some input to resolve this.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you've passed "*" as the masking character so that seems expected. And then the function parameter `charactersToIgnore` is never used within your `deidentify_with_mask` function.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide me a sample code @BrendanA.

Answer (score 0):

characters_to_ignore must be set within the character_mask_config